# What am I doing wrong with a dropdownlist in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I put them in context, I am from Chile, and I am building a reservation engine and in the engine I need to define the current account of the clients, for that I made a list and placed it in a select and it gives me the following
error undefined method `current_acounts_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x00000000024478
Did you mean? current_accounts_path

How do I solve the problem Thanks
I share the codes thanks

Controller

```
class CurrentAccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  
  def index
    @currentaccounts = CurrentAcount.all
  end

  def new
    @currentaccount = CurrentAcount.new
    @clients = Client.all
  end

  def create
    @currentacount = CurrentAcount.new(set_params)
    @currentacount.client_id = @client.id
    if (@currentacount.save)
      redirect_to current_accounts_path, notice: "Cuenta Corriente Guardada" 
    else
      render :new
      flash.alert = "No se pudo Guardar Cuenta Corriente"
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    @currentaccount.client_id =  @client.id
    if (@currentaccount.update(set_params))
      redirect_to current_accounts_path, notice: "Modificacion de Cuenta Corriente Guardada" 
    else
      render :edit
      flash.alert = "No se pudo Modificar la Cuenta Corriente"
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def destroy
    if (@currentaccount.destroy)
      redirect_to current_accounts_path, notice: "Eliminada Cuenta Corriente"
    else
      redirect_to current_accounts_path, notice: "No se pudo Eliminar Cuenta Corriente"
    end
  end

  private

  def set_params
    params.require(:current_acount).permit(:mail, :client_id, :number, :bank, :city, :telephone_contact, :type_account)
  end

  def set_client
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  end

end
```

Model

```
class CurrentAcount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client

  
end
```

Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @currentaccount do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :client, collection: @clients.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] } %>
  <%= f.input :number, label: "Numero cuenta Corriente" %>
  <%= f.input :type_account, prompt:"Elija tipo de cuenta", collection: ["Cuenta Correinte", "Cuenta Vista", "Cuenta de Ahorro"]%>
  <%= f.input :bank, prompt:"Elija un Banco", collction: ["Banco de Chile", "Banco Internacional", "Scotiabank Chile ", "BCI", "Corpbanca", "Bnaco BICE", "HSBC Bank (Chile)", "Banco Santander-Chile", "Banco Itaú Chile", "Banco Security", "Banco Falabella", "Deutche Bank (Chile)", "Banco Ripley", "Rabobank Chile", "Banco Consorcio", "Banco Penta", "Banco Paris", "Banco Bilbao Vizcaya Argentaria, Chile (BBVA)", "Banco BTG Pactual Chile", "BancoEstado", "Banco Do Brasil S.A.", "JP MORGAN BANK, N.A.", "Banco de La Nacion Argentina", "The Bank of Tokyo-Mitsubishi UFJ, LTD"] %>
  <%= f.input :city, label: "Ciudad"%>  
  <%= f.input :telephone_contact, label: "Telefono"%>
  <%= f.input :email_contact, label: "Email"%>
  <%= f.submit "Agregar" %>
  <%= link_to  "Volver", current_accounts_path(@reservation.client_id) %>
<% end %>
```

Thank for all

Comment: according to the error you have a typo in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model to have the correct spelling. Naming needs to be consistent:

```rb
CurrentAccount                 # model
resources :current_accounts    # routes
models/current_account.rb      # filenames and
views/current_accounts/        #   directories are also important.
@current_accounts              # instance variables; less important,
@current_account               #   but why make them different.
```

Run a generator to get a default set up:

```
$ bin/rails generate scaffold_controller CurrentAccount
```

---

Just to note a few places:

```rb
@currentaccounts = CurrentAcount.all
#        ^^                ^

@currentaccount = CurrentAcount.new
#        ^^               ^

@currentacount = CurrentAcount.new(set_params)
#        ^               ^
```

The actual error is coming from the form builder, because it is using `CurrentAcount` model to generate a URL for the form action:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @currentaccount do |f| %>

# which is trying to get the url
<%= url_for @currentaccount %>

# which is trying to call a named route based on the class name
# something like this:
<%= send "#{@currentaccount.model_name.route_key}_path" %>
# => undefined method `current_acounts_path'
```

Comment: I realized what you explain to me last night and I changed it, Thanks for answering